# How do I log in to my personal Windows 10 using a FIDO2 key?

Tags: windows, login

I'd like to user a FIDO2 key to log into Windows 10. There are various guides explaining how to add a key to a Microsoft web account, or to Windows 10 sign in options, but neither result in showing up as an option when I try logging into Windows.

How can I configure windows to use my FIDO2 key to log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there are certain prerequisites you need to have before you can use the *FIDO2* functionality.

1) The *FIDO2* capability requires using the Windows 10 October 2018 Update (version 1809) and Microsoft Edge browser. 
(**Note:** that the update maybe still blocked due to some driver issues like Intel drivers - I don't know all the issues have been addressed - you have to check yourself [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history).)

2) Microsoft is using the [`WebAuthn`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/) and `FIDO2 CTAP2` specifications, which require that both a private and public key get added to a device. Organizations will need to have a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) on the device to store these keys. The TPMe can be implemented via hardware or software (usually present in business notebooks like HP, DELL).

What makes a key compatible with Microsoft solution?  You should read it at: [What is a Microsoft-compatible security key?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/microsoft-compatible-security-key)

The details about the Microsoft's implementation is described at [All about FIDO2, CTAP2 and WebAuthn](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Identity-Standards-Blog/All-about-FIDO2-CTAP2-and-WebAuthn/ba-p/288910) .

The support for enterprise version will be available as the enterprises raise their version up to the above named update and MS enables it for them (full support in AD and Azure AD).

### To enable a Microsoft Account (MSA) to use *FIDO2*

1) You are already using Windows 10 1809 (October update) as said above you can setup *Windows Hello* to use *FIDO2*

2) To enable it go to your [Microsoft Account page](https://account.microsoft.com/account) and enter the **Security\More Security** from Windows Edge (it won't work at IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.)

- If you have setup everyting you should see the following screen:

[image: Correct screen with FIDO2 support]

- If something did not work out you will see the following:
  [image: Not supported message]

Comment: This allows someone to log into their Microsoft account from Edge, but it has no effect on the sign in options for Windows 10.

Comment: @ConorPatrick You are **linking** via Edge your security key to the  Azure ID (via Azure AD) profile - then you can log into your Windows 10.  To my best knowledge, you can't have this functionality without the AD as this is aimed at the enterprises.  That is probably the reason why you did not find any guides replacing the std. login screen.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot login to  your own Windows 10 non-domain computer using a security key.

You **CAN** if you're using Azure Active Directory.  Passwordless login via hardware security key is a online AAD controlled feature and cannot be done locally without third party software.

You cannot if you're logging into a local account on a non-domain Windows 10 instance.

The "Sign-In Options" setup page that lets you select a security key describes it as "Manage a physical security key that can log you into **APPLICATIONS**."  Your Windows 10 login is not an application; your online Microsoft account login **is** an application.

Confusion is ripe around this topic because Microsoft uses the phrase "Windows Hello" instead of "login" -- most of the readers think of the user login process on a Windows 10 box when someone says "Windows Hello" and not application logins.  Edge will let you login to Microsoft online application using "Windows Hello" methods, like fingerprints or facial recognition.  Placing an app-only login method under Windows Hello that can't be used for Windows login was a bad idea that generated all this confusion.

Reference:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/adding-a-security-key-for-pc-login-in-windows-10/ffd27920-5c51-4b04-afb8-21e1a6810536?page=2

Comment: Actually you can -- at least now -- here's a very in-depth article on the topic and you can see screenshots near the bottom that show the login screen experience where you can pick a USB key to login to Windows 10 with: https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/password-less-fido2-security-key-signin-to-windows-10-haadj-devices/

Comment: That said, there are limitations to the above approach as of May 2020 - it requires Azure AD so it won't work with personal machines - it doesn't work with servers - it doesn't work with RDP - and if your FIDO2 key is associated with more than one ID, it won't let you pick which ID you sign in with at Windows login.